# Issue with RunSavedImportExport

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a VBA code on Access.

I use the function **RunSavedImportExport** using a saved import specification. Basically it imports a CSV file and puts it in a table let's call it Table_A.

Right after importing the file I have an SQL query on **Table_A**.

When running the code, it fails on the SQL query saying that **Table_A is not found** and stops at this line. If I hit again run, it continues whithout any issue.

It seems like the code moves to the second instruction while the importation has not finished yet.

Has anyone had a problem like this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not had this specific problem before, but a similar circumstance where I can only describe it as *"the code moved too fast"*.

Try adding a delay between creating the table and querying from it. Access doesn't allow `application.wait` so you could try the following:

```
Dim T1 As Variant
Dim T2 As Variant

T1 = Now()
T2 = DateAdd("s", 1, T1)

Do Until T2 <= T1
    T1 = Now()
Loop
```

This does add a one second delay, so hopefully the time length isn't an issue for yourself.

> EDIT

from what @Andre has suggested in the comment, I understand this to be a smarter alternative to my delay suggestion.

```
option explicit
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

function RunSavedImportExport()
  [some code]
  Dim T1 As Variant
  Dim T2 As Variant

  T1 = Now()
  T2 = DateAdd("s", 1, T1)

  Do Until T2 <= T1
    T1 = Now()
    sleep 50
  Loop      
  [some code]
end function
```

Comment: It is advisable to add e.g. `Sleep 50` in the loop, to avoid Access hogging the CPU. With this API declaration: `Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)`

Comment: `Sleep 50` is very short, I intended it to go into your loop. But the best way would be a loop that checks for existence of the imported table (again with a `Sleep` call in the loop).

Comment: I think you could simply loop`Do Until DCount("[Name]", "MSysObjects", "[Name] = '" & tblName & "'") = 1` with `Sleep 50` the only element in the loop